# Python loop fails to iterate over all the values of a html table

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch all the data from *all the rows* for *one specific column* of a table. The problem is that the loop only fetches the first-row multiple times but is not able to continue to the next row. Here is the relevant code.

```
numRows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr'))
numColumns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th'))

print(numRows)
# Prints 139
print(numColumns)
# prints 21

for i in range(numRows + 1):
   df = []
   value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr['{}']/td[16]".format(i))
   df.append(value.text)
   print(df)
```

As is evident from the print methods is that I have all the rows and columns of my table. So that part works. But when I try to iterate over all the rows for one specific column, I only get the first value. I have tried to solve this problem by using a **format() method** but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please try iterate through all results found instead of finding individual elements. I cannot test the code since I do not have access to HTML file.

```
found_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[16]")

for i in range(numRows + 1):
   df = []
   df.append(found_elements[i].text)
   print(df)
```

Comment: Cheers. It worked but not exactly the way I wanted.  The thing is that I am trying to replace some part of the string so that I can 'find_elements_by_xpath' dynamically. I will edit the question to make this more explicit

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code to work:

```
        rader = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr'))
        #kolonner = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/thead/tr[2]/th'))

        kolonneFinish = []
        kolonneBib = []
        for i in range(1, rader + 1):
            valueFinish = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/form[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[16]")
            kolonneFinish.append(valueFinish.text)
```

I have no idea what the + + does. So if someone knows, please comment.